How to block direct access URL such as example1.com, example2.com and example3.com url in haproxy via acl
I have successfully configured HAProxy to load balance my sites, and it is working fine. However, I need assistance with blocking direct access to certain URLs such as example1.com, example2.com, and example3.com.
Here is the current HAProxy configuration that I have set up:.
frontend http80 
        bind *:80 
        timeout client 60s 
        mode http 
        default_backend allservers 

    # Deny direct access to example1.com:8111 
    acl deny_example1 hdr(host) -i example1.com 
    acl deny_example2 hdr(host) -i example2.com 
    acl deny_example3 hdr(host) -i example3.com 

    http-request deny if deny_example1
    http-request deny if deny_example2
    http-request deny if deny_example3

backend allservers
        balance roundrobin
        timeout connect 10s
        timeout server 100s

        mode http

        server server8111 example1.com:8111
        server server8112 example2.com:8112
        server server8113 example3.com:8113


Can you please guide me on that.
